# Why am I getting stuck in an infinite loop here? - Duplicating an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, duplicates

```
function dupe(arr) {
  var arrNew = arr;
  for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    arrNew.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return arrNew;
}

dupe([1, 2, 3]);
```

I'm really struggling to work out where I'm going wrong in solving this seemingly basic problem. I was wondering if somebody could help me.

My goal is to output [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3] but instead I get stuck in an infinite loop because the length of my initial array increases.

How can I make it so that only the new array gets inserted into, and the input array stays the same?

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is that `arrNew` is referring to the same value that `arr` is referring to (the declaration doesn't assign a copy of `arr` to `arrnew`, so when you're iterating over `arr`, you're at the same time *adding* new elements to it, so its length always remains greater than i.

Why not just do something like this?

```
function dupe(arr) {return arr.concat(arr);}
```

Comment: Ah ok thanks. I'm vaguely aware of the concept of pointers (only just getting into programming now) but didn't know that's what was happening here. Does the same thing happen when assigning other types of variables?
(And thanks, I found the concat method while googling around the topic but still needed to make sure I understood why this wasn't behaving why i thought it would.

Comment: @NRMano Right. What's interesting to note here is that Arrays in javascript are Objects and objects are copied/compared by reference, so the declaration just creates a new, local *alias* for the formal parameter `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign an array as a value, you get back a pointer to the array, not a copy of the array. So you are appending to the same array you are iterating over, and this leads to an infinite loop.

You can check that they are the same for yourself:

```
> var arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
undefined
> var arr2 = [1, 2, 3];
undefined
> var arr3 = arr1;
undefined
> arr1 === arr2;
false
> arr1 === arr3;
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are passing a **pointer** of `arr` to `arrNew`.
if you change either, both will change.

**use `var arrNew = arr.slice(0);`**
 
to pass a **copy** of `arr` to `arrNew` and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting `arrNew = arr`, you can set `arrNew = arr.slice();`

The slice() method returns a shallow copy of an array into a new array object.

This way arrNew and arr are not referencing the same object in memory.

```
> arrNew = arr;
> arrNew === arr // returns true

> arrNew = arr.slice();
> arrNew === arr // returns false
```